# Display Quotes Each day Depending on Date

Tags: php, mysql

iam trying to make a quote of the da each day displays a new quote  from dataBase selected sequentially depending on date , which mean i will put 365 Quote and i expect each day displays a new Quote ..

Comment: Google "daily quote database php" perhaps? `* ahem *`

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Right out of the gate you have a problem because you did not account for leap years ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to store all the quotes in database with specific display date.

then just compare date of today with database date and display the Quotes. DONE.